# Cannot get Ndef Message from NdefFormatable object

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

The objective of the `readData` method below is to return the NDEF message, whether the tag supports the NDEF format or is "NDEF Formatable".

```
class WritableTag (tag: Tag) {
    private val NDEF = Ndef::class.java.canonicalName
    private val NDEF_FORMATABLE = NdefFormatable::class.java.canonicalName

    private val ndef: Ndef?
    private val ndefFormatable: NdefFormatable?

    val tagId: String?
        get() {
            if (ndef != null) {
                return Tools.byteArrayToHex(ndef.tag.id)
            } else if (ndefFormatable != null) {
                return Tools.byteArrayToHex(ndefFormatable.tag.id)
            }
            return null
        }

    init {
        val technologies = tag.techList
        val tagTechs = Arrays.asList(*technologies)
        if (tagTechs.contains(NDEF)) {
            Log.i("WritableTag", "contains ndef")
            ndef = Ndef.get(tag)
            ndefFormatable = null
        } else if (tagTechs.contains(NDEF_FORMATABLE)) {
            Log.i("WritableTag", "contains ndef_formatable")
            ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag)
            ndef = null
        } else {
            throw FormatException("Tag doesn't support ndef")
        }
    }

    fun readData(): NdefMessage {
        if (ndef != null) {
            ndef.connect()
            if (ndef.isConnected) {
                return ndef.ndefMessage
            }
        } else if (ndefFormatable != null) {
            ndefFormatable.connect()
            if (ndefFormatable.isConnected) {
                return ndefFormatable.ndefMessage // Unresolved reference: ndefMessage
            }
        }
        throw Exception("Cannot read ndef message")
    }
}
```

I can get the `ndefMessage` from the `ndef` tag but not from the `ndefFormatable` tag. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `ndefFormatable` tag is not in the right state to store `ndefMessage`s, it needs to be formatted to store `ndefMessage`s.

It is not possible to read an `ndefMessage` from `ndefFormatable` Tag, it is basically a blank card that is indicating that it could store a `ndefMessage` if it was setup to store them.

All you can do is `format` it and then `write` a `ndefMessage`