# Notable to get NFC tag information only get ID and Tech Type in react native nfc manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

I am trying to read information form Nfc tag that is written here is my code. NFC reads tag id and its type not able to read other information that we write I am using react native nfc manager

```
try {
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      const tag = await nfcManager.getTag();
      if(tag){
       const message= await nfcManager.ndefHandler.getNdefMessage();
        const status = await nfcManager.ndefHandler.getNdefStatus();
        await  db.collection('Tags').add({
          tag:tag,
          Data:message,
          status:status,
        })
      }
    }
```

[image]

only ID and Techtype it showns not able to show idr information

I am epecting to someone guide me issue that I faced in my code and Want able to run NFC manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get Ndef Message from NdefFormatable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823172/cannot-get-ndef-message-from-ndefformatable-object)

Comment: The Tag does not have any Ndef data on it, any data that is on it is not structured in the way for Ndef, use one of the other TechTypes to read any data on the Tag (If there is any)

Comment: yes I postd image as well that show techtypes that I get in tag node

Comment: No that is not my answer than you pasted above link

Comment: No amount of coding will read data that does not exist, the Tag is empty (blank) of Ndef Data.  I suggest that you use a third party app like `TagInfo` by NXP to check the contents of the Tag (You can save what it reads to a file and copy the text in to your question).

Comment: Ok But  tag has data its already working fine

Comment: It would not show a TechType of "android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable" if the Tag contained Ndef Data. This is only shown when the Tag needs to be formatted before it can store Ndef data.

Comment: Is there any way to get data of different format Because I dont know How data write to tag ?

Answer (score 1):

the content of the message you wrote is in payload for that just call the method `getNdefMessage()` like this

```
NfcManager.ndefHandler.getNdefMessage()
        .then(message => {
          // NfcTech.Ndef.uri.decodePayload(message['ndefMessage'][0]['payload']);
          settag((Ndef.uri.decodePayload(message['ndefMessage'][0]['payload'])).toString())
        })
        .catch(err => {
    // catch error here
})
```